# mysql, join on same table?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table that looks like

> id, parentId, name
>   1,  null,     first
>   2,  null,     second
>   3,  1,        child of first

I want to do a query so that I can end with with rows that looks like

> 1, null,  first
>   2, null,  second
>   3, first, child of first

so basically something like

`SELECT id, (SELECT name FROM pages WHERE id=parentId), name FROM pages`

of course obviously that query is horrible.

Comment: Why do you think is that query horrible?

Comment: For better readability, use caps for the SQL part of the queries.

Comment: @markus: dependant subqueries are a major bottleneck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like the following, it is restricted to two levels Parent and child. 
It wont work for 3 or more levels eg. Parent->Child->Child

```
SELECT  Parent.ID,
        Child.name,
        Parent.Name
FRom    yourTable as Parent LEFT JOIN 
        yourTable as Child On Parent.ParentID = Child.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select id, parent = null, name from pages where parentid is null

union all

select id, parent = top.name, name = sub.name
from pages sub
     join pages top on sub.parentid = top.id
```

Comment: Also check out http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html for handling hierarchical data in general.

Comment: @sasfrog: The article is now at http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/.