# MySQL - join on same table?

Tags: mysql, database, join, subquery, left-join

I'm trying to implement [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218095/mysql-join-on-same-table), which shows how, using table aliases, you can effectively join to the same table you're running the query on.

Consider the following (simplified) table of football teams:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| id | name      | next_fixture_against | url_token |
=====================================================
| 1  | Hull City | 2                    | hull      |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 2  | Everton   | 1                    | everton   |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

I'm trying to write a query that fetches the names of a given team and its next opponent.

**Approach 1: left join**

Here's what I came up with by adapting the above answer:

```
SELECT main_team.name, opposition_team.name as against
FROM teams AS main_team
LEFT JOIN teams AS opposition_team
ON main_team.name = opposition_team.next_fixture_against
WHERE main_team.url_token = 'hull'
```

That produces:

```
-----------------------
| name      | against |
=======================
| Hull City | NULL    |
-----------------------
```

If I remove the `WHERE` clause, it *does* work, but, strangely, it comes out in the reverse order from that which I'd expect, i.e.

```
-----------------------
| name    | against   |
=======================
| Everton | Hull City |
-----------------------
```

rather than name = Hull City, against = Everton.

(This is purely a point of interest - clearly I need the `where` clause as I'm targeting a particular team, not all teams.)

**Approach 2: sub-query**

I came up with the following, alternate approach:

```
SELECT
    name,
    (SELECT name FROM teams WHERE id = ???) AS against
FROM
    teams
WHERE
    url_token = 'hull'
```

...but I'm not sure what to replace `???` with to get the inner sub-query to reference the outer one.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are just switching these two: `main_team.name = opposition_team.next_fixture_against` -> `main_team.next_fixture_against = opposition_team.id`

Answer (score 1):

You need `ON main_team.id = opposition_team.next_fixture_against`. You tried to use the team name rather than id in the join.

Don't worry, we've all done this.

Comment: Agh, actually that was a typo and doesn't resolve the problem unfortunately. The deleted answer below does, however. +1 for spotting the typo, though - thanks.